# Setup GPO Logon script using powershell

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory, domain-controller, logon-scripts

I have my logon script setup in GPO and looks like it wont work.

The script was tested running good.

My question is that do I have to change `-ExcutionPolicy` on all Client PCs? the target PC I tested against, I setup `-ExcutionPolicy Restrict`. Then I use `-ExcutionPolicy bypass` when I setup Parameter in Logon script.

Where did I do wrong?

My domain controller is 2008R2, Clients are Windows7, Powershell 2.0 at least

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Figured out. Security Filter is on, I need to set my test user in there.
There is no parameter needed, By default that GPO will use `bypass` as excutionpolicy.